# Heap Sort in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I write the heapsort code in prolog?

My input will look like:

```
?- heapsort([4,3,5,2,1],L).
```

And the above question will produce `L = [1,2,3,4,5]` as output.

Comment: As I remember, heapsort is basically binary tree sort on an array. So one would use the predicate `nth0/3` to pick out elements i, 2i and 2i+1 from the list standing in as array. The problem is that a list is not an efficient representation of an array as it is always scanned from the first element onwards. In fact, an "array" may be best represented as a compound term. Then you can also mutate the array using `arg/3` and `setarg/3`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It would probably be easier to represent the heap as a tree. Then first insert all elements to a min-heap one by one, then remove them one by one (now in ascending order). The difficulty is to implement insert and delete from a min-heap represented as a binary tree. But let's see what OP says about it.

Comment: What have you tried? Asking us to code for you is a no no here.

Answer (score -2):

```
heapsort(List, Sorted) :-
    % Heap-sort
    sort(List, Sorted).
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed heap-sort?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes, 100% guarantee heap sort no problem.

Comment: Swipl seems to use merge sort? https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2

Comment: GNU Prolog uses merge sort, as evidenced looking in their source code